# changing\hiding mouse cursor over plugin

Tags: plugins, cross-browser, cross-platform, firebreath

I'm developing a plugin for FF/Chrome/IE/Gecko.
Within my plugin i need to change or hide the mouse cursor.
The plugin is windowless (and should remain so).

I have tired changing the style of DOM containing the plugin but it does not work, as does calling SetCursor/ShowCursor (probably because of the Sand Boxing).

I know this is technically possible ( Adobe Flash is able to change mouse cursor, I.E YouTube flash player)

Thanks,
Koby

Answer (score 0):

There is no sandboxing for regular plugins in any of these browsers at present; if SetCursor/ShowCursor isn't working then most likely the problem is actually that the browser is calling SetCursor/ShowCursor itself and so your calls are ineffectual (they get overridden).

Keep in mind that the browser wants to retain control of the mouse cursor because it may be layering something else over your plugin when you're in windowless mode. I have never seen a plugin set the cursor in windowless mode -- if there is a way, it is more along the lines of a hack than a real strategy and would likely not be supported, guaranteed to work on all browsers, or even likely to continue working when the browser is updated.

Flash is certainly able to change the cursor... when it is windowed, as in the case you mentioned above. If you make your plugin windowed you should be able to do it too.